# Multiple Views combined into 1 Table/View using UNION (SQL)

Tags: sql, powerbi

I created a DB that combines data from multiple views into 1 view for me to pull into PowerBi. I use Power Query to append the views into 1 table for me to pull from and create my visuals. The problem is the DB is growing much larger then originally planned and my computer is have a very rough time doing that append now that we have grown from 48 to 300+.

My question is is there a way using SQL to combine these multiple DB View into one view prior to PowerBi?

Each DB (300+) has a single View created that is extracting the data needed to be combined. Each view contains all the exact same columns.
[image: EXAMPLE PICTURE OF DB]

Any help would be appreciated. I have read into using "UNION ALL", but not sure thats the correct route to go.

Comment: I don't know PowerBI or Power Query. I don't know if that is the reason I am having problems understanding your request. You say you have a database where you have a view based on multiple views. Then you ask us if it is possible to have a view based on multiple views. How is that? Either you have them and know it is possible or you don't have them. Then you have "grown from 48 to 300+". 300 what? Gigabytes? Tables? Views? Then, why do you have many views containing the same columns? This doesn't seem to make much sense.

Comment: Then you do know that views get their data at runtime? If you combine views, you are eventually building a very large - and maybe complex - query. My gut feeling says you are doing something very wrong, but I cannot be sure. Maybe this is how PowerBI works? It's doubtful, though. I've tagged your request `powerbi`, so maybe someone who knows about that can give you advice.

Comment: At last: Keep in mind that we don't know anything about your database. When you say you have views and you base views on them, then we have no idea what you are actually dealing with. Maybe you should show some simplified sample views and tables, so we get an idea. And please tell us what DBMS you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is is there a way using SQL to combine these multiple DB View into one view prior to PowerBi?

You can write a SQL Query like this

```
select 'View1' Source, a,b,c,d, . . . from View1
union all
select 'View2' Source, a,b,c,d, . . . from View2
union all
. . . 
union all
select 'ViewN' Source, a,b,c,d, . . . from ViewN
```

Note UNION ALL simply concatenates the results, whereas UNION deduplicates them.  So always use UNION ALL if you want all the rows from all the views.

And then save that as an additional view, or call it through the [Value.NativeQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/native-query-folding) Power Query function.

Comment: I will try this, it sounds like exactly what I need thank you!